# Convert text file to word document and format it using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, formatting

I made a **web-scraper** with python and bs4.
It scrapes about a hundred websites and saves the scrapes to text files.
The text files can be read easily, but i want a way to **format the text** so as to make it more easy to read **using some artificial intelligence**. can that be done?

I know how to convert text files to word document but i want to know how to actually format the text for example making proper nouns bold and underlining stuff using artificial intelligence. is there some python module.

I have googled for an entire day but was unable to find anything!

I am sorry if my question does not provide enough information. Ask me and i will add more details.

My webscraper that saves scrapes to text file:

```
import bs4
import requests
import sys
import re 
import unicodedata
import os
import random
import datetime
import linecache
import time
import urllib3

#create a for-loop which scrapes the links one by one from the links.txt file
for linenum in range (0,100):
    try:
        #open link num 1-49 from links.txt
        linenumthlink = str(linecache.getline('links.txt',linenum))
        if ('youtube' in linenumthlink):
            print("Skipping link which does not allow scraping....")
        else:
            #print the current number of website being scraped along with it's url
            print(str(str(linenum)+" "+str(linenumthlink)))
            #give a name to the file in which current scrapes are going to be put
            filename=r"D:\Huzefa\Desktop\The Big Researcher\\"+str(linenum)+".txt"
            #get request for current website from the links.txt file
            headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;     x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",     "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
            res = requests.get(linenumthlink, headers=headers)
            #convert the current website to BeautifulSoup object
            #res.raise_for_status()
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
            #open the file in which the current scrapes are to be put
            file = open(filename , 'wb')
            #loop through the websites html code and write each paragraph to the text file and then leave a line
            for i in soup.select("p"):
                f=i.text
                file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", f)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
            file.close()
            #sleep for 30 seconds so the unknown error does not occur
            #time.sleep(30)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: And which part of that exactly are you stuck on? One obvious split: knowing what the formatting should be, or applying it in the document?

Comment: I want to know how to apply the formatting to the document

Comment: Then please provide a [mre] focusing on your attempt to do that.

Comment: I am sorry if i dont meet your expections i am new to python and I could not Attempt to do that !  thats why I am here. I searched the internet to learn how to attempt to do that but the internet did not help me. Again i am sorry for not meeting your expectations!

Comment: Well what are you using to write the document, even? Maybe look for a library and read their docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the python-docx module. It contains tools for doing your job!
install it using pip

```
pip install python-docx
```